# Why does the y-scroll appear

Tags: css, scroll

I set absolute values for main blocks, but the scroll still doesn't disappear.
Why the margin of error is 9px?
Why when I remove blue block's property `justify-content: space-between;` or add `padding-bottom: 9px;` to red's block scroll disappears?
Many thanks!

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbh50kL6/)

Comment: `section` needs to have `min-height` in stead of `height` to make the scoll disappear... Apparently the total content height doesn't fit in `100vh - 60px` making the section overflow. It just needs to to be allowed to grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is overflowing in the red container:

[image]

This causes the scrollbar to appear. It's clearly visible in this case, but also text without descenders will use up that space. The selected text shows this:

[image]

The padding you mentioned causes the text to move up just enough to fit in the red container entirely.

You could also add `overflow:hidden;` to the CSS `.red` rule to prevent any part of the text from overflowing.

Comment: No it's not.
The effect is reproduced without the letter `g` and `.red` has fixed line-height value.

Comment: @АнтонАндреев it is actually. I understand the confusion, but `font-size` behaves differently across font-families, and `line-height` doesn't ensure the font not exceeding that limit. I added an example in my post. [Here](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align) is a good read about font metrics. The `overflow:hidden` solution still works if you don't want to mess with the font itself.

Comment: Thank you for the article and answer!

Comment: @АнтонАндреев No problem! You can mark my answer as solved if it fixed your problem.